# batch potencias con Windows

Tags: windows, bucle-for, batch

Necesito que con un bucle FOR me ejecute su número, y las potencias en batch de Windows:

Esto es lo que tengo

```
@echo off
echo Programa para recorrido de 1 al 6
echo Pulsa una tecla para continuar...
pause>nul
for %%N in (1 2 3 4 5 6)
do
echo %%N
pause> nul
echo pulse una tecla para finalizar...
exit
```

Pero no me sale nada
Ayuda, por favor

Comment: Hola, ¿Puedes ponder el cáculo matemático y el resultado esperado de cada ciclo para ver si podemos ayudarte mejor?

Comment: Yo quiero que en el FOR poner del 1 al 10 y que me muestre el numero su cuadrado y su cubo

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios temas y cambios sobre tu script para poder resolver lo que preguntas. Veamos:

1. Estructura del loop: Te faltarían definir los paréntesis para definir el bloque interno del loop. Algo así:

   ```
   for %%N in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
   do ( 
      rem "Esto es código dentro del loop"
   )
   ```
2. [Aritmética en DOS](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php), al menos desde Windows NT, para poder hacer operaciones aritméticas hay que hacerlo mediante `SET /A variable = <operación>` por ejemplo `SET /A suma = 1 + 2`.
3. Problema con la expansión de variables. Normalmente las `%variables%` se expanden justo cuando `cmd.exe` interpreta el Script no en tiempo de ejecución, por lo que si intentas calcular el cuadrado de un valor con esto: `set /A r2=%%N*%%N` en el loop de 1 a 10, tendrás la desagradable sorpresa que luego de la segunda ejecución el valor de `r2` siempre será el último del loop, es decir 100. Por lo que hay que lograr que la expansión de cada variable se haga en tiempo de ejecución. Para poder hacer esto, en primer lugar hay que configurar: `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, con esto podremos acceder al valor en tiempo de ejecución mediante la forma `!variable!`

Fianlmente tu código quedaría:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo Programa para recorrido de 1 al 6
echo Pulsa una tecla para continuar...
pause>nul

for %%N in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) do (

  set /A r2=%%N*%%N
  set /A r3=%%N*%%N*%%N

  echo r2=!r2!, r3=!r3!
)  
echo pulse una tecla para finalizar...
pause> nul
```